Seq logging with active active configuration
I have a Docker project running MongoDB, Seq for logging, RabbitMQ, and Gunicorn app containers that I coded with Python on a server. My client wants this project to operate in an active-active configuration across two servers so that the other server can tolerate any issues with one of them. I can run MongoDB and RabbitMQ in cluster mode. I can also make my application stateless to make it compatible with an active-active setup. The only issue I’m facing is with Seq. To be honest, Seq feels lightweight and practical to me. Both our internal employees and customers are very accustomed to its interface. Therefore, I don’t want to replace my logging solution with a more complex product like Elasticsearch. How can I make Seq work in an active-active configuration?

Could you install Seq on both servers and configure your application to log to both?
Seq has scale out / high-availability mode on the road map but that is not yet available, and when it is available will be a leader-follower architecture requiring a load balancer.
